# Minimize paper to form a box (which has no top cover)

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus

I kind of solved this problem which is basically an exercise on the

[Second Derivative Test](https://math.libretexts.org/Courses/University_of_California_Davis/UCD_Mat_21C%3A_Multivariate_Calculus/13%3A_Partial_Derivatives/13.7%3A_Extreme_Values_and_Saddle_Points)

**We need to minimize the amount of paper which we would use to create a rectangular cuboid, if this box has no top cover, and if its volume is xyz = 32.**

But I am not sure of something, hence this question.

So I construct the function $$F(x,y) = xy + 2xz + 2yz = \frac{x^2y^2+64x + 64y}{xy}$$
and I need to find its minimum over this domain: $D = \{(x,y) | x \gt 0, y \gt 0\}$.

OK, I compute $Fx, Fy, Fxx, Fyy, Fxy$ and I apply the 2nd derivative test.
It gives me that we have just one critical point (4,4), and that F has  a local minimum in that point: $F(4,4) = 48$.

What bothers me is this. Why can we claim that this local minimum is also a global minimum of $F$?
My domain D is not a compact set, x can go to infinity, y can go to infinity. So I am getting confused here. I think nothing gives me the right to claim that this local min at the critical point (4,4) is a global minimum. Am I wrong? Of course the textbook says my answer is correct but why?!

Comment: A rectangular cuboid is a specific type of parallelepiped. From your function it appears you have assumed the box is a rectangular cuboid (which is not clear from your text in bold).

Comment: @smcc OK, I fixed the wording. I didn't quite know the exact English term. Yes, rectangular cuboid is what I am dealing with, and not a more general body.

Comment: You can see standard arguments in more sophisticated calculus textbooks. You have to manufacture a compact set outside of which the function is clearly greater than it is at some point inside the compact set. Then it follows from the usual extreme value theorem. The second derivative test is useless for any global arguments.

Comment: @TedShifrin Thanks, I think I see what you mean. I think also I was able to prove it by simple means that $F(x,y) \ge 48$ when $x,y$ are positive. I just use AM-GM inequality for $(64x+64y)$, and then I let $\sqrt{xy} = u$ and then, I think, a standard argument works fine.

Answer (score 0):

If a (global) minimizer exists, then it must be a stationary point (since there are no boundary points in the constraint set). If you find there is only one stationary point, then that must be the minimizer. There is no need to look at the second derivative.

The relevant theorem is this one:

**Theorem 1:** Let $f$ be a differentiable function of defined on the set $S$. If the point $x$ in the interior of $S$ is a local maximizer or minimizer of $f$ then $Df(x)=0$.

In your case, since the interior of $S$ is $S$ itself, the theorem tells you that any global minimizer must be a stationary point. Thus if you know there is a global minimizer and you know there is a unique stationary point, the that stationary point must be the global minimizer. (The above theorem says there is nowhere else the global minimizer could be: there are no other stationary points and there are no boundary points in $S$.)

---

Alternatively, if you do not already know a minimizer exists, then you could show that $F$ is convex. If $F$ is convex, then you know that a stationary point is a minimizer. To show that $F$ is convex involves essentially the same steps as you have carried out to show that $(4,4)$ is a local minimizer, but instead you prove the inequalities for all points $(x,y)$ on the interior of the domain ($x>0$, $y>0$).

The relevant theorem here is:

**Theorem 2:** Let $f$ be a continuously differentiable function defined on the convex set $S$, and let $x$ be in the interior of $S$. Then, if $f$ is convex, then $x$ is a global minimizer of $f$ on $S$ if and only if $x$ is a stationary point of $f$.

Comment: "If a (global) minimizer exists, then it must be a stationary point (since there are no boundary points in the constraint set). "  1) That's the point of my question. Why is this true? Is this a theorem? 2) I don't know if a global minimizer exists (in my particular problem).

Comment: See my edit. I have added the relevant theorems.

Comment: Do you need to prove a global minimizer exists or is the fact that you have been asked to find it enough? If not, then you can try to apply the second theorem (i.e. show the objective function is convex).